# Función que retorne una table en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me piden realizar esto:

> Realizar una función que reciba como parámetro: Nombre, Apellido, Fecha de nacimiento y que retorne una tabla con esa información, agregando nuevos campos, tales como la edad de esa persona y en qué ciclo se encuentra (Primera infancia[0-5], Infancia[6-11],Adolescencia[12-18], Juventud[14-26], Adul

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION Framdon (@Nombre   VARCHAR(max),
                         @Apellido VARCHAR(max),
                         @fechaN   DATETIME)
returns TABLE
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @Edad DATETIME;
      DECLARE @ESTADO VARCHAR(50)

      SET @EDAD = @fechaN
      SET @EDAD = Floor(( Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), Getdate(), 112) AS INT)
                          - Cast(
                                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), @EDAD, 112) AS
                                            INT)
                        ) / 10000)

      IF( @EDAD >= 5 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO = '[infancia 0-5 ] '
        END

      IF( @EDAD > 5
          AND @EDAD = 11 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='[iinfancia 6-11]'
        END

      IF( @EDAD > 12
          AND @EDAD = 18 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='adolecente[12-18]'
        END

      IF( @EDAD > 14
          AND @EDAD = 26 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='Juventud [14-26]'
        END

      IF( @EDAD > 27
          AND @EDAD = 59 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='Adultes[27-59]'
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='persona de la tercera edad'
        END

      RETURN
  END
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Explícalo a través de una edición a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que necesitas caminar antes de correr. Antes de pensar en una función, necesitas tener correctamente la consulta. Para eso tienes que corregir tus cálculos. Empecemos con el dato que se repite constantemente y no tenemos: la edad.La podemos asignar como una columna de una tabla que puede ser solo una expresión de SELECT.

```
DECLARE @Nombre   VARCHAR(max) = 'Luis',
        @Apellido VARCHAR(max) = 'Cazares',
        @fechaN   DATETIME     = '20201020';

SELECT @Nombre AS Nombre,
       @Apellido AS Apellido,
       @fechaN AS FechaNacimiento,
       Edad
FROM (SELECT ( Cast(CONVERT(char(8), Getdate(), 112) AS INT)
             - Cast(CONVERT(char(8), @fechaN, 112) AS INT) ) / 10000 AS Edad)x(Edad);
```

Si te fijas, por ahora estamos usando variables en vez de parámetros. No tenemos nada que indique una función,solo una consulta sencilla. También simplifiqué el cálculo de edad usando tipos de dato más pequeños y quitando la función FLOOR que no es necesaria cuando dividimos enteros.

Con eso, vamos a revisar los cálculos para agrupar la edad en etapas. Para eso tenemos la expresión `CASE` que nos permite evaluar varias condiciones. Una ventaja es que cada condición se evalua en orden y solo necesitamos validar el límite superior. Puedes notar como las condiciones cambiaron porque las que tenías nunca iban a mostrar valores incorrectos la mayor parte del tiempo.

```
DECLARE @Nombre   VARCHAR(max) = 'Luis',
        @Apellido VARCHAR(max) = 'Cazares',
        @fechaN   DATETIME     = '20201020';

SELECT @Nombre AS Nombre,
       @Apellido AS Apellido,
       @fechaN AS FechaNacimiento,
       Edad,
       CASE WHEN Edad <= 5  THEN 'infancia [0-5] '
            WHEN Edad <= 11 THEN 'infancia [12-18] '
            WHEN Edad <= 18 THEN 'adolecente[12-18]'
            WHEN Edad <= 26 THEN 'Juventud [14-26]'
            WHEN Edad <= 59 THEN 'Adultez [27-59]'
            ELSE 'persona de la tercera edad' END AS Estado
FROM (SELECT ( Cast(CONVERT(char(8), Getdate(), 112) AS INT)
             - Cast(CONVERT(char(8), @fechaN, 112) AS INT) ) / 10000 AS Edad)x(Edad);
```

Ya tenemos una consulta que regresa los datos que necesitamos. Ahora convertirla en función es muy fácil, solo necesitamos cambiar el cabecero y asegurarnos de tener nombres únicos para todas las columnas.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Framdon (
        @Nombre   VARCHAR(max),
        @Apellido VARCHAR(max),
        @fechaN   DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT @Nombre AS Nombre,
       @Apellido AS Apellido,
       @fechaN AS FechaNacimiento,
       Edad,
       CASE WHEN Edad <= 5  THEN 'infancia [0-5] '
            WHEN Edad <= 11 THEN 'infancia [12-18] '
            WHEN Edad <= 18 THEN 'adolecente[12-18]'
            WHEN Edad <= 26 THEN 'Juventud [14-26]'
            WHEN Edad <= 59 THEN 'Adultez [27-59]'
            ELSE 'persona de la tercera edad' END AS Estado
FROM (SELECT ( Cast(CONVERT(char(8), Getdate(), 112) AS INT)
             - Cast(CONVERT(char(8), @fechaN, 112) AS INT) ) / 10000 AS Edad)x(Edad);
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen dos opciones para realizar lo que comentas.

***MSTVF***

Puedes realizar una función de este tipo, que retornará una tabla desde una variable tipo tabla.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Framdon (@Nombre   VARCHAR(max),
                         @Apellido VARCHAR(max),
                         @fechaN   DATETIME)
returns @data TABLE (
    Nombre VARCHAR(max), 
    Apellido VARCHAR(max),
    fechaN   DATETIME,
    edad datetime, 
    ciclo varchar(50))
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @Edad DATETIME;
      DECLARE @ESTADO VARCHAR(50)

      SET @EDAD = @fechaN
      SET @EDAD = Floor(( Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), Getdate(), 112) AS INT)
                          - Cast(
                                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), @EDAD, 112) AS
                                            INT)
                        ) / 10000)

      IF( @EDAD >= 5 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO = '[infancia 0-5 ] '
        END

      IF( @EDAD > 5
          AND @EDAD = 11 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='[iinfancia 6-11]'
        END

      IF( @EDAD > 12
          AND @EDAD = 18 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='adolecente[12-18]'
        END

      IF( @EDAD > 14
          AND @EDAD = 26 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='Juventud [14-26]'
        END

      IF( @EDAD > 27
          AND @EDAD = 59 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='Adultes[27-59]'
        END
      ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @ESTADO ='persona de la tercera edad'
        END

      Insert into @data(
      Nombre, Apellido, fechaN, edad, ciclo)
      values
      (@Nombre, @Apellido, @fechaN, @Edad, @estado);

      RETURN

  END
```

Viendo el código, solo se cambia, que el return indica un objeto de un tipo con unas columnas, las cuales llenamos antes del return.

La otra opción, que sería una función tipo Tabla, cambia ligeramente la sintaxis, y tiene alguna complicación más.

***TVF***

```
CREATE FUNCTION Framdon (@Nombre   VARCHAR(max),
                         @Apellido VARCHAR(max),
                         @fechaN   DATETIME)
returns  TABLE
return 
  (
    SELECT @Nombre AS Nombre,
        .....
  );
```

Es algo más compleja, porque tienes que resolver todo en una select. No le indicas ni el tipo, ni vas llenando las filas de salida.

Pueden ser más eficientes.

[Crear funciones definidas por el usuario](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: si  estuve viendo y al terminar con la nueva forma que fue como lo termine ,lo que me fijo es que al ejecutar la funcion con los valores de entrada no me esta convirtiendo la fecha en edad y no me la esta validando en los if directamente me muestra una fecha default si no mal me equivoco es la determinada del datetime

Comment: Haber.....es que tienes un lio con los campos datetime y como calculas la edad. Pero eso no tiene que ver con la función. No puedes definir @edad como Datetime y esperar que sea >5 o > 12 .... Eso no es así. Indepdendiente de la función. Consigue extraer la edad en una select. Y cuando el resultado sea un INT. entonces se lo asignas a una variable int y la evalúas en los IF. Por ejemplo. Consigue que esto devuelva la edad en años. `Declare @fechaN datetime= '20100101'` Cuando lo tengas, Declara edad como Int.

Comment: En resumidas cuentas, lo que tienes es una funcíón, que aunque resuelva una tabla porque tiene varias columnas, la puedes depurar directamente sin ser función. Coges todo el contenido que tienes, pones las variables con declares en una ventana de querys, y les asignas diferentes valores, y cuando veas que todo resuelve lo que pides, Entonces creas la función. Si el código no te resuelve fuera, no deberías de hacer la función porque son complicadas de depurar.

Comment: SI  revise y no solo eso tenia mala las variables y sintaxis dela funcion , sino que tambien  las condiciones  if else  ya pude solucionar muchas gracias.. por el apoyo

Comment: En lo personal me sirvio muchisimo la forma como propones devolver los datos en la función, muchas gracias.

Comment: Un placer poder aportar algo de valor. @anRoswellHarrisMaiden